# Sending multiple type of content in same request

Tags: angularjs, multipart, angular-http, request-headers

I'm using angular 1.5 and I have to hit a service to upload a file. In the same service I have to pass a JSON as request body too.

When I'm using `Content-type: application/json` multipart for file is not working, if I use  `Content-type: undefined` then multipart will work but JSON param wont work. So is there any way like I can set a `value` of a `key-value` pair of a json as a `multipart`? Or any other way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this way and you will be fine:

```
$scope.uploadMultipart = function(file, jsonObject, uploadUrl){
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('json',JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
    formData.append('file', file);

    return $http({
        url: uploadUrl,
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    });
};
```

---

I would not recommend it but thats how you could add the file as a part of a JSON object. In that way you be able to post a in content-type `application/json`.

```
$scope.uploadHack = function(file, jsonObject, uploadUrl){

    var aReader = new FileReader();
    aReader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    aReader.onload = function (evt) {

        //append file to json as raw data
        jsonObject.file = {
            content:  aReader.result,
            name: file.name,
            size: file.size
        };

        $http({
            url: uploadUrl,
            method: 'POST',
            data: jsonObject,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            transformRequest: angular.identity
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes. Here we are appending a stringifyed json to multipart. Is there the opposite way? the multipart in a JSON ?

Comment: @AmirSuhail Why do want to do this? Even the backend handling (JSON.parse) is much easier with this kind of multipart structure - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: Yes. But backend have to call somethere service when it get multipart. If we do the above one the data will come as multipart params, not as a request body. To get the data in request body I need to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I did'nt understood `new File([new Blob([s])], file)` whats is the `s` in Blob array?  It should `new Blob([json.stringfy(file)])]`, right?

Comment: @AmirSuhail I make it work with FileReader. Check the update